# How to get values from nestable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-nestable

I have a nestable tree from https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

I want to get some values from list, I need to create a list  with parents and their children in order, each item have: id, descripcion, fechainicio, fechafin, horas.

How to get each data from list for build my list in json format

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
    <ol class="dd-list" id="lista-actividades">
        <li class="dd-item dd3-item actividad" data-id="1">     
           <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>     
           <div class="dd3-content">             
              <input name="id" type="hidden"  value="1">                 
              <input name="descripcion" type="text" value="Actividad 1" >                 
              <input name="fechainicio" type="text"  value="2017-01-01">                 
              <input name="fechafin" type="text"  value="2017-01-01">                 
               <input name="horas" type="text"  value="1">                   
           </div>     
           <ol class="dd-list">
              <li class="dd-item sub-actividad" data-id="2" >     
                 <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">drage</div>          
                 <div class="dd3-content">             
                    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="2">                 
                    <input name="descripcion" type="text" value="actividad 1.2">                 
                    <input name="fechainicio" type="text" class="" value="2017-01-01">                 
                    <input name="fechafin" type="text"  class="" value="2017-01-01">                 
                    <input name="horas" type="text" value="1">                 
                  </div>
             </li>     
           </ol>
         </li> 
     </ol>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: We should start with the basics. A id in html must be unique.

Comment: Have you checked here? https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable